# Ways for Execute gacutil in remote machine

Tags: scripting, gacutil

Is there a way to execute gacutil in to a particular (remote) machine given the IP address (or the workstation name) of the machine?

The machines in question are on an Active Directory Domain.

The user running the script probably won't have any special rights on either their local or the remote machine.

Some cases, will be administrator in machine.

Operating system is Windows XP , and remote machine Win2008 and Win2003.

Any programming language is fine but ideally scripting:

- DOS Batch file (bat, cmd)
- VBScript (WSH)
- psexec
- C# (worst option for me)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried Remote Gacutil? http://remotegacutil.codeplex.com/

You can always use psexec:

```
copy %Proj_folder%\SomeDll.dll \\destinationHost\c$\Temp
psexec \\destinationHost gacutil -I c:\temp\SomeDll.dll
```